# Manage gulp different environment different files and path

Tags: gulp

In my normal flow I have two css included

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="external.css">
```

Instead of this using gulp I have combined this two and minified it into `res_style.css` so it should include

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="build/res_style.css">
```

But i want that on development environment it should include two files (`style.css`,`external.css`) only and on production it should include res_style.css . Is there any way gulp can handle this automatically on basis of environment ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `yargs`

In commend line, you can add for ex: `gulp --env development`

In gulp config:

```
var argv = require('yargs').argv;
console.log(argv.env);
if (argv.env === 'developmenet') {
    // generate 2 css file
} else {
    // generate 1 css file
}
```

Use gulp src to replace text inside html file.

```
var src =  path.join('index.html');
var dest =  path.join('build/index.html');

gulp.src(src)
    .pipe(replace('<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">', ''))
    .pipe(replace('<link rel="stylesheet" href="external.css">', '<link rel="stylesheet" href="build/res_style.css">'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(dest));
```

Comment: Generation is not the problem , i want to automise it in file in my index.html file where i am including this css.

Comment: Its possible to do with gulp inject. Just mention comment and files and it will be appended.